# Suggestions about php editors and file sync programs

Tags: sync, php, aptana-studio

I'm working with ubuntu and lately I decided to learn php. I have everything setup and I'm currently using **aptana 3** as my **php** editor and for file sync. It seems like the process for file sync is too much, it has to check all files just to upload 1 file. So if someone can tell me how to update a file at once without delay, that's welcomed. I find **aptana** not being what I like. It's a good editor, but I would like to know if there are alternatives out there. Can someone suggest a good **php** editor for **ubuntu**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after a GUI editor, try sublime text 2, you can use it for free (you don't have to purchase a license anyway).

Are you editing remote files directly?

I would just use rsync over SSH, DRBD is too complicated;-)

rsync example

```
rsync -avz --progress --delete source user@host:/home/user/code
```

Alias above and run it whenever you have changed code locally.

BTW: You can also consider `sshfs` to mount folder on remote host via SSH.

Comment: I had to type this question in order to actually search for Aptana 3 shortucts, seems like I can upload the file I'm editing simple by hitting shift+ctr+u that's progress. I'll take a look at sublime text 2

Comment: Looks like you are editing a remote file, if SSH is enabled on that server, simply use sshfs to mount the remote folder and edit files just like local files;-)

Comment: Is that fast? Cause doing the same thing with aptana is a pain in the xxx lol

Comment: I don't know how aptana does the file update (most likely FTP/SFTP). Should be pretty much the same but sshfs's advantage is that it appears to be a local file system and it does the update seamlessly, you don't notice that, I reckon it should work better than what you are using now.